# Main view stacks on the same page after calling partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this action that returns different partial view based on the selected value from the drop down list.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Foo(SomeViewModel VM)
        {
            var model = VM
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                if (model.SelectedValue == 1 || model.SelectedValue == 2 || model.SelectedValue == 3)
                {
                    // ...
                    return PartialView("PartialView1", model);
                }
                else if (model.SelectedValue == 4)
                {
                    // ...
                    return PartialView("PartialView2", model);
                }
                else (model.SelectedValue == 5)
                {
                    // ...
                    return PartialView("PartialView3", model);
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Main View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<div>
    <h2>Paint Computation</h2>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Foo", "Controller",
 new AjaxOptions
 {
     HttpMethod = "POST",
     UpdateTargetId = "Result"
 }))
    {
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h5>Type of Paint</h5>
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.PaintType, "Value", "Text"),
                "Please Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <br />

        // Some HTML helpers
            <input type="submit" value="Compute" class="btn btn-default" id="Submit" />

        </div>
    }
</div>

//This is how I render my partial view using jQuery in my main View:

    <div id="Result">
        <hr />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Submit').click(function () {
                $('#Result').load('/Controller/Foo');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Whenever I clicked the button, the partial view appears, but when I clicked it again for the 3rd or 4th time, the main view content stacks on the same main view. I tried to use the inspect element and that's how I determined that it stacks the same main view elements.

Is my way of calling the partial view is right? As much as possible I want to use ajax for calling the partial view every time the button is clicked. Please guide me to correct it. Thanks.

Here's the [image: screenshot] of the problem.

Comment: Personally I'd have two (or more) actions rather than one action that does everything - but otherwise the principle is sound, although I can't see why you'd put an ajax call in the partial (it appears to be something to do with the submit) - this looks like it should be something that is setup once on view load and the results loaded via ajax.  It looks like there's some additional code/html not included.

Comment: It looks like your issue is that each partial has its own `<div id='Result'>` so you're adding this multiple times so getting multiple results.   The 'stacking' is most likely caused by bootstrap's 'col-md-10'.

Comment: I'd like to call the partial view every time the button is clicked based on the m.SelectedValue from the dropdownlist using ajax so the page won't refresh everytime the user submits. Can you suggest what approach should I do so the main view does not stack? @freedomn-m

Comment: Take `<div id='Result'>` out of the partial and put it in the main page.

Comment: it's on the main page. I just separate it on the code

Comment: In the question's code, you have *"This is how I render my partial view using jQuery:"* then `<div id="Result">` - ie it looks like you're saying the Result div is in the partial - perhaps that's "how" you render it rather than "what" you render.  Is the 'main view' the partial?   Have you included what's in the partial?  Maybe you could clarify in the question exactly what code is where?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post. the `<div id="Result">` is in the main view. So everytime I clicked the button, the partial view will render in the main view. @freedomn-m

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Submit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Controller/Foo',
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#Result').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now it works. I changed my code and use the code above. I use .html() rather than .append() or .replaceWith(). Now every time i click the button, it changes the `<div id = "Result> content.`

Comment: That should be the same as `$("#result").load(url)`.  There was no mention of `.append()` in the question which would generate duplicates each time.